# Unable to Install APK Via ADB Shell

Tags: adb, android-emulator

`pm install /mnt/sdcard/Documents/ClientFrontEnd.apk` command excuted on rooted device. This command is working via terminal. but when it comes to installer application it gives error.

```
$ pm install /mnt/sdcard/Documents/ClientFrontEnd.apk
Error is pkg: /mnt/sdcard/Documents/ClientFrontEnd.apk Killed.
```

Comment: why are you not doing it from the desktop PC side - `adb install ClientFrontEnd.apk`?

Comment: Agreed with @t0mm13b why don't you use adb itself, unless you are testing something in the emulator or don't have drivers. My first instinct is that you have an antivirus running on the device and it detects something in the APK that it doesn't like so its removing it. Do you have antivirus running?